# Best Persistence model for iPhone development

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data, persistence

I'm finishing my second book on iPhone development (Beginning Iphone 3 Development - Mark/LaMarche) and, while this book covers the 4 main persistence mechanisms, I'm still not sure which one to use for my application.  My data model is not very intricate, but I do need some relationship definition and functionality.

So what are the seasoned developers using out there and could you please point me to some sample code that involves more than one entity with some basic relationships?

I would really appreciate any input.

Rod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use SQLite for production with very few exceptions.  If you are one of this exceptions you will know it :)

SQLite has too many advantages to choose any other for production.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus.
Just to clarify (once again, new guy here), when you say use SQLite, you mean outside of Core Data? From my understanding, Core Data uses SQLite in its core as well, isn't that right? I'm having the darnest time with Core Data from the examples I've found. It all just seems a bit over engineered, but who am I to know.

Comment: Core Data can use several different types of persistent stores, SQLite, Binary, In-Memory and XML (on the desktop). I was stating that you should be using Core Data with a SQLite persistent store for production.

Comment: I've been using (and learning) Core Data with SQLite and so far it's been GREAT! Thanks!